# Новичковый вопрос. Ссылка на несколько других таблиц в одной

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

В базах данных не разбираюсь вообще, так что вопрос может быть очевидным для некоторых))

Вопрос касается того, как лучше реализовать такую концепцию сайта: есть пользователи, которые создают таблицы бд на сайте и добавляют в эти таблицы пользователей (пользователи - те, которые так же как и создатели могут получить возможность выгрузить себе таблицы в которые их добавили). После создания таблицы у пользователя должна быть выгрузка тех таблиц, которые он создал. Вопрос такой: как у одного пользователя реализовать вызов всех этих таблиц на страницу?

То есть как привязать конкретные таблицы к конкретным пользователям, которые их создали. При том, что есть отдельная таблица с этими пользователями?

То же самое касается не создателей, а пользователей, которых добавили в эти таблицы, таблица должна проверяться кто в нее добавлен и у тех выгружаться.

Эта таблица не является списком пользователей, а является таблицой с другой информацией (в случае этого примера с таблица с текстовыми заданиями)

Были мысли по поводу того, чтобы сделать отдельную ячейку в бд, где каждому пользователю через запятую записываются названия таблиц, но не уверен в целесообразности такого подхода.

Также была мысль создавать по две таблицы, где есть tablicaName и tablicaName_users. Мол создавать еще одну дописывая _users. Но это кажется нагромождённым вариантом

Заранее благодарю за подсказку новичку

Comment: Уточните что за таблицы, в вашем вопросе сначала упоминается связка полльзователи-группы а потом пользователи-таблицы - не понятно.

Comment: Описание отредактировал. Должно стать более ясным

Comment: Никогда не давайте юзерам возможность создавать таблицы как сущности вашей базы. Если вы новичок нет смысла что-то столь сложное делать, для начала разберитесь, для себя, что такое связи в базах данных и как работают простейшие связи, а потом можете приступать к подобным заданиям

Comment: Согласен с @InDevX, если не понятно как работать с бд, лучше почитайте документацию или посмотрите примеры построения архитектуры бд, что такое связи между таблицами, какие они бывают. Потом уже беритесь за построение архитектуры.

Comment: Скорее всего ваша задача решаема с помощию двух таблиц. В первую заносятся все пользователи, а во второй хранятся связи между ними. Но как вам посоветовали, для такой нетривиальной задачи, лучше изучить хотя бы основы SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос то, могу предложить реализовать так:

Создать таблицу 'users' в которой будет вся информация о пользователе (user_id, user_name и прочее).

Создать таблицу 'tablici' в которой будет хранится вся информация об всех таблицах и об id пользователя, кто ее создал (tablica_id, user_id, tablica_name, tablica_text). В итоге таблиц будет много (если будут создавать столько), но у каждой будет свой пользователь.

Потом просто права настроить на самом сайте уже. Также сделать к ним формы, чтобы у администратора(создателя, другого пользователя с правами) при нажатии на пользователя выводилась вся информация о нем и просмотр таблиц для самого человека, который их создал.

Comment: tablici.. никогда и ничего так не называйте

Comment: приму это к сведенью. для пользователя старался, чтобы понятней было на его же примере)